# Is my using gperftools to profile a R script with RCpp correct?

Tags: c++, r, profiling, rcpp, google-perftools

I am trying to profile a R script with the last (third) approach in http://pj.freefaculty.org/blog/?p=140. I wonder if what I do (described in the following) is correct?

Firstly,  in `my.cpp`, the link says to add `#include <gperftools/profiler.h>`, which
doesn't work for me. I found that the header is located in a different
dir, and what works for me is `#include <google/profiler.h>`.

Then I put the following around some code to be profiled

```
ProfilerStart("./myprofile.log") 
//the part of the code to be profiled
ProfilerStop()
```

Next,
I created a script mytest.R, which contains the following

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-lprofiler")
sourceCpp('my.cpp') #  for compiling the cpp file
... (use some functions defined in my.cpp
```

Lastly, when I run in bash

```
$ R -f mytest.R
```

it runs a R session, run the content of `mytest.R` inside R, and exit R after outputting

```
PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 353/0/1988
```

Does it mean the profiling was run successfully, or not? "interrupts" and "evictions" look troublesome to me.

It does generate the profiling output to `myprofile.log`, with

```
$ google-pprof --text /usr/bin/R myprofile.log
```

I can see

```
Total: 353 samples
      37  10.5%  10.5%       37  10.5% b313b2cb
      21   5.9%  16.4%       21   5.9% b313b2b8
      18   5.1%  21.5%       18   5.1% b313b2ce
      15   4.2%  25.8%       15   4.2% _IO_str_pbackfail
      10   2.8%  28.6%       10   2.8% b69be532
       9   2.5%  31.2%        9   2.5% b69be520
       7   2.0%  33.1%        7   2.0% b69bd111
       6   1.7%  34.8%        6   1.7% b313b2dc
       6   1.7%  36.5%        6   1.7% b69bd132
       5   1.4%  38.0%        5   1.4% b69bb50f
       5   1.4%  39.4%        5   1.4% b69bb6d8
       4   1.1%  40.5%        4   1.1% b3133bda
       4   1.1%  41.6%        4   1.1% b3134c2b
       4   1.1%  42.8%        4   1.1% b313b298
       4   1.1%  43.9%        4   1.1% b69bd159
       3   0.8%  44.8%        3   0.8% b3134c32
       3   0.8%  45.6%        3   0.8% b313b29b
       3   0.8%  46.5%        3   0.8% b313b2c8
       3   0.8%  47.3%        3   0.8% b69bb6e0
       3   0.8%  48.2%        3   0.8% b69bb6f1
       3   0.8%  49.0%        3   0.8% b69bcef1
       3   0.8%  49.9%        3   0.8% b69bd100
```

No entry in the last column is human-readable, so I wonder if some way to make them readable?

I wonder if I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably just a binary with stripped symbols.

Comment: How would you retain the symbols that are readable? Thanks.

Comment: I would start small. Build a standalone C++ programs with g++, see that perftools works.  Then deal with R.  For the Debian/Ubuntu package symbols are in an extra package r-base-core-dbg; that works with gdb and may help here.  I haven't had time for a worked example, but as I told you on your earlier question my (older) HPC slides cover this...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
google-pprof --text /usr/bin/R myprofile.log
```

if you issue sourceCpp with  `verbose=T` you'll see the file path and generated object file...

```
Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /tmp/RtmpyxYB19/sourcecpp_79831e029f

/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_2.so' --->8---
```

so try using (in this instance)

```
google-pprof --text /tmp/RtmpyxYB19/sourcecpp_79831e029f/sourceCpp_2.so myprofile.log
```